# How can I simulate generic dynamic dispatch in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, dynamic-dispatch

I'm using a trick I've learnt in F# to simulate existential types, and I want to see if this works in Rust:

```
/*
To replicate:
type SuperArrow<'a, 'b> = 
    | Fn of (('a -> 'b) * string)
    | Compose of SuperArrowCompose<'a,'b>
and SuperArrowCompose<'a,'b> = 
    abstract member eval : SuperArrowComposeEvaluator<'a, 'b, 'r> -> 'r
and SuperArrowComposeEvaluator<'a, 'b, 'r> = 
    abstract member apply<'c> : SuperArrow<'a, 'c> -> SuperArrow<'c, 'b> -> 'r
*/

//#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyFnWrapper<A, B> {
    f: Box<Fn(A) -> B>,
    n: String,
}

impl<A, B> MyFnWrapper<A, B> {
    pub fn new<F: 'static + Fn(A) -> B>(f: F, s: String) -> Self {
        MyFnWrapper {
            f: Box::new(f),
            n: s,
        }
    }
}

trait SuperArrowComposeEval<A, B, R> {
    fn apply<C>(&self, &SuperArrow<A, C>, &SuperArrow<C, B>) -> R;
}

trait SuperArrowCompose<A, B> {
    fn eval<R, E: SuperArrowComposeEval<A, B, R>>(&self, &E) -> R;
}

struct SuperArrowComposeImpl<A, B, C> {
    fnA: Box<SuperArrow<A, C>>,
    fnB: Box<SuperArrow<C, B>>,
}

impl<A, B, C> SuperArrowComposeImpl<A, B, C> {
    fn new(fnA: SuperArrow<A, C>, fnB: SuperArrow<B, C>) {
        SuperArrowComposeImpl {
            fnA: Box::new(fnA),
            fnB: Box::new(fnB),
        }
    }
}

impl<A, B, C> SuperArrowCompose<A, B> for SuperArrowComposeImpl<A, B, C> {
    fn eval<R, E: SuperArrowComposeEval<A, B, R>>(&self, evaler: &E) -> R {
        evaler.eval::<C>(self.fnA, self.fnB)
    }
}

//#[derive(Debug)]
enum SuperArrow<A, B> {
    Function(MyFnWrapper<A, B>),
    Compose(Box<SuperArrowCompose<A, B>>),
}
```

([gist](https://gist.github.com/emcake/f85df38f583ce7939d8f3c1a1fdafd70))

The double-interface layer hides the intermediate `'c` existential type in the composition behind the first interface (`SuperArrowCompose<'a,'b>` in the comment at the top).

The reason this works in F# is that it can dynamically generate the code needed for the `'r`-specific implementation at runtime. This clearly isn't possible in Rust and it won't allow me to have a trait with generic type parameters:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `SuperArrowCompose` cannot be made into an object
  --> existential.rs:57:13
   |
57 |     Compose(Box<SuperArrowCompose<A,B>>),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SuperArrowCompose` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: method `eval` has generic type parameters
```

It needs to be generic to allow it to be generic on the return type, but at the same time it needs to be dynamic to hide the specific `C` type that joins the two functions.

Comment: Unless I'm missing a trick here I don't think Any is what I want. The best part of this trick is that it preserves the types throughout - as I understand it Any is more akin to Object from .NET.